# Counting function that returns sequential outputs

Tags: python, printing, count, return, output

Is there a function like where every time a keyword or action is called, it triggers a return or count to change to a value that you can assign an output
meaning based on how many times you say "take a drink" the output will change until -in the case below- its "all empty:

if action = "take a drink"

```
add 1 to count.drink

count 0 = print("full")

count 1 = print ("3/4 left")

count 2 = print("1/2 left")

count 3 = print ("1/4 left")

count 4 = print("all empty")
```

action: take a drink

```
count = 1

reaction "3/4 left"
```

action: take a drink

```
count = 2

reaction "1/2 left"
```

action: take a drink

```
count = 3   

reaction "1/4 left"
```

action: take a drink

```
count = 4

reaction "all empty"
```

Comment: I'm recommending using Dictionary to solve this issue Dictionary in python can call to functions/methods. you can set "take a drink" as a key and increment your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment i'll suggest a solution.

```
actDictCount = {"take a drink":0}

actDictList = {"take a drink":["action1","action2","action3"]}

action = "take a drink"

actDictCount[action] +=1

print(actDictList[action][actDictCount[action]])
```